# Why do native speakers sometimes call some one 'name + boy'?

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language, colloquial-language

I've heard male native speakers call their male friends by their name + boy.
For example, a man's name is David, and a male friend of his once said to him 'Hey David boy...' And I've heard another male call his friend Lucas 'Lucus boy'.
Why do they call their friend in this way? Does it represent familiarity? Is it respectful? If I call a not-very-close friend in that way, is that offensive? And is this only between males? Is there a female version of this?

Comment: In what country were these native speakers? It's not at all common in the UK. It would be familiar and only appropriate when addressing a younger person. Northern equivalents might be "David, lad" or "Mary, lass".

Comment: I've never heard of this outside of the old TV show *The Waltons*, where one character was named "John-Boy".  I could imagine a particular group of friends having an in-joke where they called each other "David-Boy" etc. in imitation of  *The Waltons*, but it's not common in any subculture I'm familiar with.